# c++ array[] vs malloc(). are these 2 vriables the same?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Here we have `arr1` and `arr2`...

```
int  arr1[3]{};
int *arr2 = (int *)std::malloc(size_t(int) * 3);
```

and i think entities of arr2 should be stored in the heap compared to the arr1 that is stored in the stack memory.

**question**:
Is there any reason to use arr2 if its not going to get bigger or smaller during the code?

Comment: `arr1` is not a pointer, it's an array.

Comment: *"arr1 and arr2 are pointers..."* No `arr1` is not a pointer. It's type is `int [3]`.

Comment: Also:  `arr1` will be automatically destroyed when it goes out of scope. You can also take the `std::size` of `arr1` while that information is lost in `arr2`.  `arr2` is uninitilaized, `arr1` is not.

Comment: Allocating arrays on heap may be useful as data returning from functions when `std::vector` is unavailable (for example, when you are creating a library that may be linked with C code), but I think `int *arr2 = new int[3];` is better.

Comment: isnt (arr1 == &arr1[0]) ? @Yksisarvinen

Comment: @TedLyngmo sorry edited mybad

Comment: `arr1 == &arr1[1]` will be false. `arr1 == &arr1[0]` will be true because arrays in this type of expressions are converted to a pointer to the first element of the array.

Comment: They are not the same https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-to-pointer-decay

Comment: malloc usually doesn't have a place in C++, even new/delete are no longer recommended. For arrays of fixed size use std::array, for dynamically resizable arrays use std::vector. With manual memory managment it is just too easy to write buggy code. And if you have to do your own memory managment have a look at std::make_unique (or rarely std::make_shared)

Comment: The expression `arr1 == &arr1[0]` evaluates to `true`, even though one is a pointer and the other is an array.  `==` does not compare _types_.

Comment: Try using `int arr[1000000000];` in your code and you know why you might need `int *arr = new int[1000000000];`. (hide the `new` in a unique/shared_ptr)

Comment: @DrewDormann It only compares true since `arr1` decays to a pointer to the first element. So both sides of the `==` are the same type after decay. Otherwise the comparison could give anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The memory held by `arr1` is guaranteed to be allocated only in it's scope. The memory `arr2` points to is yours till you `free()` it (or exit the program), thus you might pass it as a return value, store it, etc. Also, `arr2`'s allocation likely takes more bytes in practice, as memory allocation usually maintains blocks of free memory. So allocating via `malloc` or `new` is both slower and takes more memory (but sometimes required for other benefits).

Answer (score 2):

> `arr1` and `arr2` are pointers

No, `arr1` is not a pointer. In particular, `arr1` has type `int [3]`, it's just that it **decays** to a pointer to its first element i.e., `int*` in certain contexts due to **type decay**.

---

> Is there any reason to use arr2 if its not going to get bigger or smaller during the code?

`arr1` will be automatically destroyed when it goes out of scope while for `arr2` you will have to free the memory(pointed by `arr2`) manually. That is, you'll have to do *manual memory management*(not recommended).

Moreover, *smart pointers* should be preferred over raw pointers if/when you decide to use dynamically allocated memory.

Or better yet would be to use(if allowed) standard containers like `std::vector` altogether etc.